# Wordpress don't show | in the <title> attribute on the index.php

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am currently using this code to display the name of the post/page and of the blog in my wordpress theme:

```
<title><?php wp_title(''); ?> | <?php bloginfo('name'); ?></title>
```

The problem is that the  of the index.php looks like this:
| name of the blog

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `functions.php` add

```
add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );
```

And in your header under your `Content-Type` meta add, like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<?php
    if ( ! function_exists( '_wp_render_title_tag' ) ) :
        function yourtheme_render_title() {
            ?>
            <title><?php wp_title( ' ', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
            <?php
        }
        add_action( 'wp_head', 'yourtheme_render_title' );
    endif;
?>
```

Should be working once you set the title of your blog/web page on the Settings.